# the set of sequences $0\leq f(n)\leq \tfrac{1}{n}$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be the set of bounded functions from $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We will equip $X$ with the supremum norm. Let $K=\{f:0\leq f(n)\leq \tfrac{1}{n}\}$. Prove that $K$ is compact.

I have proved that $K$ is closed. So all that is left is to show that $K$ Is totally bounded. This is my attempt, I think it's very close I just need a push in the right direction. Let $\epsilon >0$ be given, then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $\tfrac{1}{n}<\tfrac{\epsilon}{2}$. Define the set of functions $f_{0}=0$.

For $1\leq j\leq N-1$, $f_{j}(n)=\tfrac{j}{nN}$. Each of these are in $K$. I claim that $B_{\epsilon}(f_{j})$ cover $K$. First note, if $n\geq N$, then $|f(n)-f_{j}(n)\leq 2\tfrac{1}{n}< \epsilon$.

So all that I need now is, for all $n<N$ there exists a $j$ such that $|f(n)-f_{j}(n)|<\epsilon$. I can't straighten this one out. A hint would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: The supremum norm is infinite on some sequence. Hence it is not a norm... Maybe you mean *bounded* sequences?

Comment: No, the functions you have choosen are not the centers of a covering. Take $\epsilon=1/8$ and any $f$ such that $f(1)=3/4$

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini yes bounded functions I added that. Also I fixed my definition of $f_{j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to take $f_0 = 0$ is good. Then you only have to deal with $n<N$ which is something equivalent to $\mathbb R^N$. But there (in $\mathbb R^N$) bounded and closed sets are compact.

**edit** More precisely: you don't have to take a single function $f_0=0$ but you can take the points which give the covering in $\mathbb R^N$ and extend to the whole $\mathbb N$ with zeroes.

Comment: Beautiful hint. Thank you.